# Status 405 - docker - artifactory

Tags: nginx, docker, artifactory

I get the following error when pushing images to docker artifactory:
`v1`:

```
Error: Status 405 trying to push repository abc-docker-local: "{\n  \"errors\" : [ {\n    \"status\" : 405,\n    \"message\" : \"Method Not Allowed\"\n  } ]\n}"
```

**I use nginx. My config file looks like:**

```
server_name localserver;
rewrite ^  remoteserver/artifactory/api/docker/abc-docker-local/v1 redirect;
if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
    set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
}

location / {
        proxy_read_timeout  900;
        proxy_pass_header   Server;
        proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
        proxy_pass          http://remoteserver:9081/artifactory/api/docker/abc-docker-local/v1;
        proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

In Artifactory I set the repo as `v1`. I also tested with `v2` but no end points are returned. The exact error for v2 is:

```
Index response didn't contain any endpoints
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you specify what Artifactory and docker client versions you're using?

Comment: docker version

Client:
 Version:      1.8.2-el7
 API version:  1.20
 Package Version: docker-1.8.2-10.el7.x86_64
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Built:        
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
Server:
 Version:      1.8.2-el7
 API version:  1.20
 Package Version: 
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Built:        
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64                                     

Both are set to use api v2
Artifactory front end displays: You are running Artifactory version 4.2.2 

thanks!

Comment: There have been many changes to the api over the last few versions of both - can you try with docker 1.10 and Artifactory 4.7?

Comment: I have put a lot of effort in setting up Artifactory 4.2.2
Do you know by any chance what is the version of Docker working with Artifactory 4.2.2? (if any)

Comment: Docker 1.8 should work - seems to me you most probably have an issue with your nginx config... upgrading to the newest Artifactory should not cause you any particular issues (or risk) but you will get the [reverse proxy snippet](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+a+Reverse+Proxy) feature and save yourself all of the hassle.

Comment: thanks I updated Artifactory to 4.7 but when I click in View > "Revese Proxy Configuration Snippet" the result is empty 

I tried to assign the port 80 to the "Docker Reverse Proxy Settings" got similar error: "v2 ping attempt failed with error" 

Can you please copy/paste a sample snippet accompanied with proxy settings in Artifactory? I will replace the values and will try it in my ngix/docker vm

Comment: I continued my questions in the comments below the proposed answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result is blank you must have not inserted all of the required configuration - here's an example from my sandbox: 
[image: reverse proxy config]

At any rate, this is the config that Artifactory generated which I use which works for me with Docker 1.10 (but also worked with Docker 1.8 and 1.9) installed on a remote Ubuntu machine while my Artifactory sandbox is my machine.

Note the certificates location I have which is not common `(certs\myCert.cert)`  so change it to wherever your SSL certs are, and also that i'm using ports `4441` and `4442` for `V1` and `V2` respectively:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    ## add ssl entries when https has been set in config
    ssl_certificate      certs\myCert.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key  certs\myCert.cert;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    ## server configuration
    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen 9091 ;

        server_name localhost;
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
            set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
        }
        ## Application specific logs
        ## access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-access.log timing;
        ## error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-error.log;
        rewrite ^/$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
        rewrite ^/artifactory/?(/webapp)?$ /artifactory/webapp/ redirect;
        location /artifactory/ {
        proxy_read_timeout  900;
        proxy_pass_header   Server;
        proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080/artifactory/;
        proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

    ## server configuration
    server {
        listen 4441 ssl;


        server_name localhost;
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
            set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
        }
        ## Application specific logs
        ## access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-access.log timing;
        ## error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-error.log;
        rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/docker-local-v1/$1/$2;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        location /artifactory/ {
        proxy_read_timeout  900;
        proxy_pass_header   Server;
        proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080/artifactory/;
        proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }

    ## server configuration
    server {
        listen 4442 ssl;


        server_name localhost;
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = '') {
            set $http_x_forwarded_proto  $scheme;
        }
        ## Application specific logs
        ## access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-access.log timing;
        ## error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost-error.log;
        rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/docker-local-v2/$1/$2;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
        location /artifactory/ {
        proxy_read_timeout  900;
        proxy_pass_header   Server;
        proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080/artifactory/;
        proxy_set_header   X-Artifactory-Override-Base-Url $http_x_forwarded_proto://$host:$server_port/artifactory;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        proxy_set_header    Host              $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you have artifactory and nginx in the same machine?

In contrast, I have nginx and docker in one machine and artifactory in another

Comment: I changed my settings to: internal port 8081, external port 8443,  docker registry bound to port 80 and API is v2 (v1 isn't shown in settings page) an I get this error:
************************************************************************************
"Error: Status 400 trying to push repository tomcat: "{\n  \"errors\" : [ {\n    \"status\" : 400,\n    \"message\" : \"Unsupported docker v1 repository request for 'removed'\"\n  } ]\n}"
*************************************************************************************

Again docker and nginx are in the same VM. artifactory is in another VM

Comment: After updating to docker 1.9.1 I'm getting this response:
"unknown: Method Not Allowed"

Complete version is  docker-1.9.1-25.el7.x86_64

Comment: Without your log (with specific debug entries enabled) I'm afraid it's difficult to tell, If you used my template correctly.

 I suggest you contact support@jfrog.com, seems like it's an issue with your config to me.

Comment: I already contacted them but haven't heard from support@jfrog.com

Any idea why I'm getting this from artifactory:
"unknown: Method Not Allowed"

Comment: The only possible reason is that your nginx is forwarding requests to the wrong endpoint - try checking its log and Artifactory's request\access logs to see where it's actually going to.

Comment: I revisited the config files and after some changes it seems to be one step closer.

This is the latest message:
"The push refers to a repository [server:port/tomcat] (len: 1)
430e8c6b6fad: Pushing 1.024 kB
EOF"

It seems that a connection with the endpoint is established correctly but for some reason only 1 mb is uploaded

Comment: I received help from support@jfrog.com
The issue was that I used the port 80 which docker client redirect to https automatically and since I don't have security certs in place then was failing.
I changed the port and worked like a charm.

Comment: @sat want to turn that into an answer?